# SQL Server subquery in cross join returns error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, subquery, cross-join

I have tables `A`, `B` and `C`. Now table `A` as column `A1`(Primary Key), table `B` has column `B1`(Primary Key) and table `C` has columns `A1`(Foreign Key to Table `A.A1`), `B1`(Foreign Key to Table `B.B1`).

Now I'm writing a query which list all rows from `A` and `B` and a bit column which will be set to to 1 if a row is found matching in table `C` otherwise 0.

```
SELECT 
     ISNULL((SELECT CAST(1 AS BIT) 
             FROM C 
             WHERE C.A1 = A.A1 AND C.B1 = B.B1),0) AS [TAG],
     A.A1,
     B.B1
FROM A CROSS JOIN B
```

This query is producing an `Subquery returned more than 1 value.` error even though the query has no duplicate rows after combining the `A1` and `B1` columns.

Comment: post the result of the subquery alone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
SELECT  CAST(COALESCE(c.b1, 0) AS BIT)   TAG
FROM
        (
            SELECT  A1, B1
            FROM    A CROSS JOIN B
        ) D LEFT JOIN C
                ON  c.A1 = d.A1 AND
                    c.B1 = D.B1
```

Comment: The columns `A1` AND `B1` are `varchar`. I have to dynamically create the bit column in query after checking existence in `C` table.

Comment: Brilliant. Worked just as expected.